# Accessing database from SQL Server present on PC by using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I have found out that it is possible to connect PHP to sql server, but it was mentioned that it is compulsory to have static IP. Is there any alternative solution or this static IP thing is compulsory? Can anyone who has previously done this before, could clear my confusion?

Comment: you are talking about localhost development ?

Comment: @fico7489 Web host development